# Without, free from, lacking, etc.: Unambiguous total negation with "OR"?

Tags: conjunctions, negation, logic

In the following, “does not cause” seems to be clear negation, and total negation requires “or”, therefore:

> The widget does not cause deformities or cracks

However, it is unclear to me whether the following types of words and phrases are strong enough in negation to enable an “or” to clearly express total negation.

For example:

> The widget leaves a product:
>
> *without* X or Y
>
> *free from* X or Y
>
> *lacking* X or Y

Questions:

1. Would, for example,  “. . . without X or Y” above unambiguously mean “having no X and having no Y”?
2. What is the term for this class of words and phrases and are there other common members of the group?

Comment: Why not say *The widget leaves the product X-free and Y-free*, and eliminate the possibility of ambiguity?

Comment: This is a tough question. On my PhD exam in semantics, I was asked to describe the similarities and differences among the negative predicates _not have_, _lack_, _be without_, and _be missing_. There are a lot of them, and they don't line up in any easy way. Try fitting them (and _be free from_) into this sentence, for instance: _Bill ..... a finger on his left hand._ By the way, they're simply called [Negatives](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf).

Comment: essentially, using `nor` in place of `or` removes the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sentence is going to begin with *The widget leaves a product* and end with *without X or Y*, it means that the widget somehow fixes the product. If the widget is an antivirus and antispam/malware program, e.g., and the product is your computing device, then you can use one of these three:

> **The widget leaves a product without X or Y**

is clear and means that there will be neither X (viruses) nor Y (spam/malware) in the product. The same is true for

> **The widget leaves a product without X and Y**

and

> **The widget leaves a product free from X and Y**

but the option with "**lacking X or Y**" is, IMHO, undesirable.

Comment: Note that **lacking X and Y** is better, but if you're trying to get rid of X and Y, it's bad phrasing because *lacking* is a word with negative connotations (at least in American English).

Answer (score 1):

Either of these is better than what you have, since they are no longer ambiguous:

1. The widget does not crack or cause deformities.
2. The widget causes neither cracks nor deformities.

And yes, those mean different things.  Your sentence is very unclear, so it could go either way.  I don’t know which sense you intended.

You could even use *nor* in place of *or* in the first one if you wanted:

- The widget does not crack nor cause deformities.

Comment: I think you misread OP's first example. The last word is "cracks", which can only be interpreted as a second (plural) thing the widget doesn't *cause*. There's nothing to suggest it could be a verb, and that the widget itself is being claimed not to crack.

Comment: **The widget neither cracks nor causes deformities** is better style, IMHO. Regardless of whether this is or isn't what the OP wants to say.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. 
However, I am unable to change the wording because the client insists on using the phrase “without” (or “free from” or “lacking”), which are in reference documents. And so I was asked if “without X or Y” means the same as “having no X and having no Y”. The client asked me whether total negation requires “Or” after expressions such as “without”. If such phrases do not unambiguously result in negation, perhaps I can explain that to the client, but changing the wording is not an option.

Comment: Note that "lacking" is a word with negative connotation, so "lacking X and Y" would be seen as a ***bad*** thing. On the other hand, "free from X and Y" would be seen as a ***good*** thing. So if you were talking about food, you would generally say "lacking nutrients" and "free from contamination", and not the other way around. The word *without* is neutral.